# Limit date format in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using Node.js together with mysql, express and html.

When I'm retrieving the results from the database I get the following date,
`2016-03-16T00:00:00.000Z`, even though the type in mysql is date.

My query:

```
app.get('/list', function  (req,res) {
    connection.query('SELECT `ondate`,`projectname`,`hours` FROM `entries` WHERE YEARWEEK(`ondate`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) ORDER BY ondate DESC ,projectname ASC ', function(err, rows, fields) {  
    res.json({error: err, result: rows});
    });
})
```

Is there a way I can set the ondate field to ignore the time?

Comment: Which mysql driver are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(`ondate`,'%m-%d-%Y'),
`projectname`,
`hours` 
FROM `entries` 
WHERE YEARWEEK(`ondate`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
ORDER BY ondate DESC, projectname ASC;
```

Adjust the date format to the one you need.

Regards

Comment: Excellent! This is what I needed

Answer (score 2):

Hard to know exactly where the unwanted formatting is being introduced, but it might be an option to remove it as part of post processing rows...

```js
// Assuming array of rows takes shape something like this...
var rows = [{ondate:'2012-01-02T00:00:00.000Z'},{ondate:'2013-01-02T00:00:00.000Z'},{ondate:'2012-03-02T00:00:00.000Z'}];

// map rows to show only first ten chars of `ondate` field
rows = rows.map(function(item){ return item.ondate.slice(0,10); });

// business as usual...
alert(rows);
//-> 2012-01-02,2013-01-02,2012-03-02
```